# How to create a custom JButton class in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I'm afraid I don't have any code because I don't really know what I'm doing. I'm trying to learn some Java by creating a basic game and want to make a menu. What I want to do is have a class with a custom JButton (basically a JButton of a certain size and a picture on the background, formatted specially, etc.) which can be called from another class and given custom text when it is called. My question is, how do I create the custom button which can be called externally?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using `setText` and `setIcon` of `JButton`?  What are the specific format requirements that you need?  Do you know you can use HTML to format a `String` in Swing and supply it to most controls?

Comment: I was not aware of this, thank-you. What I'm trying to do is make things easier by having a custom button class which I can call several times, and not create several JButtons and then format them all seperately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a class and extend it to JButton like below and there you can change all sort of things that has to do with JButton.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class CustomJButton extends JButton {

    public CustomJButton() {
        this.setText("Custom JButton");
        // initialize
    }

    // add your own methods or override JButton methods
    public void myFunc(){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the constructor for your custom JButton, you'll want to accept a parameter that specifies the text you want the button to contain, and you'll specify the other things that you don't want to change from instance to instance, such as the size or the background image.

```
import javax.swing.*;

class MyButton extends JButton{

    public MyButton(String text){
        super(text);
        ...set size, add background image, etc...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No this button is a JButton you can create a new one
like normally, MyButton btn = new MyButton(); You just added an extra method that will format it the way you want. If you want to learn more about this topic look at object inheritance.

```
public MyButton extends JButton{


  public void doStuff(){
    this.setBackground("yourBackground");
    ...
  }

}
```

Comment: I kinda got that bit...But how do customise the button? Do I create a JButton in this class, edit stuff about it and then call it in another class?