# How can i write my winning method with an int array

Tags: java, oop, methods

```
public class Logik extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final int[] WINCASE = { 0, 1, 2 };

    JButton[] buttons = new JButton[9];

    public int counter = 0;

    public Logik() {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("TicTacToe");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(400, 420);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setResizable(false);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        f.add(p);

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
            buttons[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 120));
            buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
            buttons[i].setText("");
            p.add(buttons[i]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
            JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
            if (counter % 2 == 0) {
                b.setText("X");
                b.setEnabled(false);
                counter++;
            } else {
                b.setText("O");
                counter++;
                b.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

If you can see I made an int `Array` and I have 9 buttons and I want to know who won by writing all winning cases in that array like: `{4,5,6}{7,8,9}.` but I don't know how to use my array for Jbutton to make it work, can someone give me tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in many ways of course, for e.g. you can check the entire "board" in actionPerformed to see if you have a winner.

But I think you program could benefit from an abstraction that reminds of the game you are building; place the buttons in an matrix (instead of the array) and why not create your custom JButton by extending the java class - in that class you can add the coordination the button have in the matrix. Then it will be much easier for you to check for a winner.

With a matrix I mean two dimensional array like
`JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[3][3]`
Here is one example on how you can extends the `JButton` class
[How to create a custom JButton class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914622/how-to-create-a-custom-jbutton-class-in-java/20914815)
Of course you need to add logic related to your program in the CustomButton class, and maybe give a name meaningful in that context.

Comment: I dont know how to matrix because i only have 2 weeks of experience so far in Programming , how can i make an matrix

Comment: @michi2706 I updated my answer with what a matrix is.

Comment: Cannot invoke setText(String) on the array type JButton[] thats what i get using , 
 JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[3][3] my problem is that i dont know how to get the position of a pressed button and checking which buttons are pressed , thank u for your answer btw .

Comment: `super(text)` in your constructor... what error do you get?